# Java initialize question

Tags: java

What does the below code do when you instantiate the StudentRegistrar class?

```
public class StudentRegistrar
{
    public StudentRegistrar ();
    {
        new RecordManager().Initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't necessary destroy the `RecordManager` immediately. `Initialize()` may spawn a new thread which can then hold a reference to the `RecordManager`. Since new threads are a garbage collection root, the `RecordManager` reference will be reachable from that root and therefore it will not be cleaned up.

It really depends on what `Initialize` does!

Answer (score 1):

It creates an instance of `RecordManager`, calls the `Initialize()` method and then destroys the instance of `RecordManager`.

EDIT: Actually it won't compile due to the spurious `;`

Comment: *destroys the instance of RecordManager* should be replaced by *makes the instance of RecordManager available for Garbage Collection*

Comment: @Sean I agree that the word destroys is incorrect,  however saying that it is made available for garbage collection makes a lot of assumptions and is only true if the initialize function doesn't create an object that maintains a strong or soft reference to the RecordManager instance. sjr's response is more technically accurate.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 sjr is making just as many assumptions. Either answer is correct, depending on who's assumptions are correct